# Django - redirect list of users (other than the current user) from view

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-users

I am building a web application with Django that will allow teachers to send out multiple choice questions to students. For now, I would like to redirect all logged-in students to the question page (containing the question form) when the teacher clicks on the question. However, this requires redirecting users OTHER THAN the current user from the view which is what I am struggling with. I have looked into every form of redirect (render, HttpResponseRedirect etc) to see if I could input a user parameter but this doesn't seem to be possible. Below is the view where I would like to redirect all users to the question page.

```
@login_required
@user_is_on_course
def pushquestion(request, course_code, profquestion_id):
    course = Course.objects.get(code=course_code)
    choices = Choice.objects.filter(question=profquestion_id)
    users = get_current_users(request, course) #gets list of students
    for u in users:
        #This is where I want to redirect all users to the question page

    return render(request, 'thesis/professorquestion.html' {'profquestion':profquestion_id, 'course': course, 'choices':choices})


def get_current_users(request,course):
    active_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
    user_id_list = []
    for session in active_sessions:
        data = session.get_decoded()
        user_id_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
    return UserProfile.objects.filter(id__in=user_id_list, courseID=course)
```

I have researched the Django messages feature however this doesn't seem suitable for sending question forms to all users (seems to operate as more of an alert box). I have also looked into using long polling or web sockets to essentially add an event listener on students accounts waiting for the professor to ping a question (perhaps something along the lines of this: https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-websocket-request). However, as a beginner programmer and complete newbie to Django, I am not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree with these ideas as they seem relatively heavyweight for what I am trying to achieve (redirect a list of users from one view).

Comment: What you're asking makes no sense. You can only redirect the user that is currently requesting the page. The others haven't made a request to redirect; when they do, that's when you can redirect them.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually, websockets is the right tree to bark, as you can subscribe all logged in users to the channel and issue a command that instructs the browser to change URL. But yes, this can't be done with standard Django facilities. For ehyland: consider using [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). But you're gonna have to study up :).

Comment: @Melvyn That makes sense, I will investigate channels. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript part that has each users client making requests continuously as an async process for a flag to redirect. When you want them to redirect, set the flag to true. when each client makes their next request, the flag will tell them to redirect. then use `window.location = "redirect/url"` on each client. If the flag is false, just do nothing. For the teachure (I'm assuming this is what you mean by current user), just don't make the requests.

You could also use websockets like @Melvyn said in their comment above. Websockets uses this idea I believe.